# JS: Combine three or more consecutive days of the week

Tags: javascript

I have an array that will always contain days of the week as input. I have a const array of ordered days of the week to compare to. I first sort the input array by comparing the index of the array with the const array.

Now, I can loop through the input array to find the index between two values and determine if they are consecutive. After this point, I am lost on how to create the output I want.

For example, I have input array:

```
[sun, mon, tue, thu, fri]
```

and I want to output as:

```
sun to tues, thu, fri
```

### Edit

Sorry I didn't post my attempt when it was originally posted. Please see below:

```
const days = [
  'sun',
  'mon',
  'tues',
  'wed',
  'thurs',
  'fri',
  'sat',
];

export const combineDays = (inputDays) => {
  const sortedArray = inputDays
    .map((day) => {
      return days.indexOf(day);
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return a - b;
    });

// the string I want to return
  let dayRange = '';
//variable to hold previous day if consecutive
  let rangeEnd = '';
//range position in the loop
  let rangePos = 0;
  sortedArray.forEach((day) => {
    if (dayRange === '') {
      dayRange = days[day];
      rangePos = days.indexOf(days[day]) + 1;
    } else if (days.indexOf(days[day]) === rangePos) {
      rangeEnd = days[day];
      rangePos++;
    } else if ((days.indexOf(days[day]) !== rangePos) & (rangeEnd !== '')) {
      dayRange = dayRange + ' to ' + rangeEnd + ', ' + days[day];
      rangePos = days.indexOf(days[day]) + 1;
      rangeEnd = '';
    } else {
      dayRange = dayRange + ', ' + days[day];
      rangeEnd = '';
      rangePos = days.indexOf(days[day]) + 1;
    }
  });
  return dayRange;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for a few more hours, I got it to work but it doesn't seem DRY:

```
const days = [
  'sun',
  'mon',
  'tue',
  'wed',
  'thu',
  'fri',
  'sat',
];

export const combineDays = (inputDays) => {
  const sortedArray = inputDays
    .map((day) => {
      return days.indexOf(day);
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return a - b;
    });
  let dayRange = '';
  let range = false;
  let rangeEnd = '';
  let rangePos = 0;
  sortedArray.forEach((day, index) => {
    if (dayRange === '') {
      dayRange = days[day];
      rangePos = day + 1;
    } else if (day === rangePos) {
      if (rangeEnd !== '') {
        range = true;
      } else {
        range = false;
      }
      if (index !== sortedArray.length - 1) {
        rangeEnd = days[day];
        rangePos++;
      } else {
        if (range === true) {
          dayRange = dayRange + ' to ' + days[day];
        } else if (rangeEnd !== '') {
          dayRange = dayRange + ', ' + rangeEnd + ', ' + days[day];
        } else {
          dayRange = dayRange + ', ' + days[day];
        }
      }
    } else if (day !== rangePos) {
      if (range === true) {
        dayRange = dayRange + ' to ' + rangeEnd;
      } else {
        dayRange = dayRange + ', ' + rangeEnd;
      }
      dayRange = dayRange + ', ' + days[day];
      rangePos = day + 1;
      rangeEnd = '';
    }
  });
  return dayRange;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
const array = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];

const inputArray = ['fri','thu', 'sat'];

let indexArray = inputArray.map(item => {
 return array.indexOf(item);
});

let outputArray = indexArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}).map(item => 
 array[item]);

// EXPECTED RESULT: ["thu","fri","sat"]
 console.log(outputArray);
```

And things are gonna work